# Sample docker compose setup for web application devops

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am building a website which consists of several backend and frontend components. I want to use docker compose to deploy to a production server.

Here are the various components:

**Backend**

- C++ code to build shared libs for use with Python wrappers
- Tornado web server using python library produced from previous step
- Postgresql database server

**Frontend**

- ReactJS, webpack, node, (HTML/CSS)

Assuming that I'm keeping the mantra of one process per Dockerfile, I would like to build separate images for each of the "layers" shown above - *BUT*, are my identified layers "correct" - does it even make sense to separate between the backend and frontend?

Finally, could someone show a sample `docker_compose.yml` file that allows me to assemble the website from the disparate parts - whilst taking into account, dependencies such as the tornado application depending on both the Python libs generated by the C++ application, as well as the pg database service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think splitting your backend and frontend applications absolutely makes sense.

I'm not quite sure I totally understand your requirements around a C++ application generating libs that are used by Python. Do you just mean that you have Python packages that are utilizing C libraries?

Anyway, you'll notice below that I've attached a sample `docker-compose.yml` file. I've even gone as far as including network segmentation for your front and back end applications, although this is optional and up to you.

Because you specifically mentioned the Tornado container relying on Python and the Database, I've used the service level `depends_on` key. Note, that this won't wait to start the `tornado` container until these other services are "ready," just until their containers have started. More information on this coordination can be found in the Docker docs (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dependson).

```
version: '3'
services:
  python_app:
    image: your_name/your_python_image
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      - backend

  # https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/
  database:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
    networks:
      - backend

  tornado:
    image: your_name/your_tornado_image
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - python_app
      - database
    networks:
      - frontend

  front_end:
    image: your_name/your_front_end_image
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend

# https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specifying-custom-networks
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

Happy to work through more of this with you and build up to a solution you're comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks very much for the sample docker_compose.yml file. The C++ application generates shared libraries which SWIG then uses to autogenerate a python library which wraps around the methods exported by the shared library. The Tornado application then has functions that invoke pure functions and methods from the autogenerated python code. I'm new to docker - so please bear with me (stand by) whilst I tweak the boilerplate code you provided, to get it to work. Thanks and +1 for the code.